# How to change a folder's permissions and owners?

Tags: permissions, files, filesystem

I just simply want to give the same attributes I have for "cars" directory to "animals" directory. In other words, how can I de-privilege that specific file in terms of permissions?

```
drwxrwxrwx 14 root  root  4096 Nov 26 19:41 animals
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  user  4096 Nov 16 16:59 cars
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo chown -v user:user /path_to/animals` changes both the folder owner and the group from **root:root** to **user:user**.

Now that ***root*** is no longer the owner, `sudo` is not needed anymore.

`chmod -v 755 /path_to/animals` changes the folder's access permissions to the same ones as **cars**.

If there are files and folders inside the **animals** folder and you wish to change their ownership and permissions too, add an **R** next to the **-v** option so that the commands look like:
`sudo chown -vR user:user /path_to/animals`
`chmod -vR 755 /path_to/animals`.

Typing something like **file and folder permissions linux** on Google, will give you plenty of results on how they work.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `chown` command for the ownership**, and add `-hR` flag for all its sub-files/folders.

For example, make `animals` and all files/folders under that folder owned by `user` and group `user` via command:

`sudo chown user:user -hR animals`

TIP: remove `-hR` so it applies to that folder only.

**Use `chmod` command for file/folder permission**, with following flags:

- `u` means user(owner), `g` means group, `o` means others, `a` for all.
- `r` for read permission, `w` for write, and `x` for execute.

For example, grant read and write permission for user and group, but only read permission for others, use (**add `sudo` if you're not owner**):

`chmod u=rw,g=rw,o=r FILE`

Grant read and write permission for all:

`chmod a=rw FILE`

or add read&read permission for all:
`chmod +rw FILE`

Remove write permission for others (for that folder only):

`chmod o-w FOLDER`

Add read/write/executable for user and group, but no permission for others, for specified folder and all sub-files/folders:

`chmod -R ug+rwx,o-rwx FOLDER`

**You can also use numbers along with `chmod` command to change permissions.**

- `1` = executable
- `2` = write permission.
- `4` = read permission.
- `5` = 1+4 = write & execute
- `6` = 2+4 = read & write
- `7` = 1+2+4 = read & write & execute

First number applies for owner(user), second for group, and the last for others. So, the command below means full permission for user, write & execute  permission for group and others.

`chmod 755 FILE`

Also add `-R` for folder and all sub-files/folder. For example, grant read & write for user(owner) but no permission for all others.

`chmod 600 -R FOLDER`

There are lots of tutorials about this stuff in the web, and I got one here:
https://fostips.com/tell-change-file-permission-owner-linux/